# How to pass the user context details from from bot Controller to FormDialog

Tags: botframework

### Bot Info

- SDK Platform: .NET
- Active Channels: Direct Line
- Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service

### Question

How to pass user context details from from bot Controller to FormDialog?

### Code Example

```
public virtual async Task < HttpResponseMessage > Post([FromBody] Activity activity) {
 if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message) {
  await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => {
   return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(RequestOrder.BuildEnquiryForm));
  });
 } else {
  HandleSystemMessage(activity);
 }
 return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
public static IForm < RequestOrder > BuildEnquiryForm() {
 return new FormBuilder < RequestOrder > ()
  .Message("Hello {***Pass current user name?????****}Welcome to request bot!")
  .Field(nameof(IsTermsAgreed))
  .Field(nameof(ServiceRequired))
  .AddRemainingFields()
  .OnCompletion(ProcessParkingPermitRequest)
  .Message("Thank you, I have submitted your request.")
  .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fei Han answer is correct but using a static variable might lead to some unexpected error since all instances are sharing the same value. A better approach would be using the state of the form.

**Request Order From**

In your RequestOrder class you need to add a new member variable username.

```
public class RequestOrder
{
     public string username;
     /* Rest of your member variables  */
}
```

The .Message method allows you to access the state of the form. You can get the username from the state of the form as below:

```
 public static IForm < RequestOrder > BuildForm() 
 {
     return new FormBuilder < RequestOrder > ()
      .Message(async (state) => {
          return new PromptAttribute($"Hi {state.username}, Welcome to request bot! ");
       })
      .Field(nameof(IsTermsAgreed))
      .Field(nameof(ServiceRequired))
      .AddRemainingFields()
      .OnCompletion(ProcessParkingPermitRequest)
      .Message("Thank you, I have submitted your request.")
      .Build();
 }
```

**Root Dialog**

In your root Dialog, before calling the BuildForm you need to create a new instance of your RequestOrder class and initialize username as the current user's name. Then pass your form to the BuildForm with option FormOptions.PromptInStart.

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{


    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    { 
       var form = new RequestOrder()
       {
           username = context.Activity.From.Id
       };

       var requestOrderform = new FormDialog<RequestOrder>(form, RequestOrder.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
       context.Call<RequestOrder>(requestOrderform,  SampleFormSubmitted);
    }

    private async Task SampleFormSubmitted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SampleForm> result)
    {
        try
        {
                var query = await result;
                context.Done(true);
        } 
        catch (FormCanceledException<SampleForm> e)
        {
                string reply;
                if (e.InnerException == null)
                {
                    reply = $"You quit. Maybe you can fill some other time.";
                }
                else
                {
                    reply = $"Something went wrong. Please try again.";
                }
                context.Done(true);
                await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what you get:

[image]

Comment: Hi Anita, Is it possible to open the bot window with conditional dialog? Based on button click event I wanted to open the related dialog. Example if I click on gate pass button, gate pass related dialog should start and when I click on feedback, feedback dialog should open

Comment: It would be better if you could post this as a question with a bit more detail so the whole community can help you out. Based on what I understood the short answer would be yes.

Comment: Sure, here is the expected behavior

1 User clicks on a button (We may have multiple buttons or links for different intent. Here intent may be Food Truck, Customer Demo, etc.,)
2 On button click, pass the intent value (example: FoodTruck) using custom activity name
3 Bot code catches the activity as shown here if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && string.Equals(activity.Name, "FoodTruck")
4 Throw a confirmation to user 
5 If yes start FoodTruck dialog 
6 If no end conversation with a thank you message 
I am stuck with step 4 to 6. Could you please show a code sample ?

Comment: @JosephVelliah Post it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

In following sample code, I define a constructor of SandwichOrder class with a string type parameter, then I call FormDialog as a child dialog from root dialog (not from Messages Controller directly) and pass user name as parameter, which works for me, you can refer to it.

**In RootDialog:**

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var username = "Fei Han";

        var myform = new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormDialog<SandwichOrder>(new SandwichOrder($"{username}"), SandwichOrder.BuildForm, Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);

        context.Call<SandwichOrder>(myform, FormCompleteCallback);
    }

    private async Task FormCompleteCallback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<SandwichOrder> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"The form is completed!");
        context.Done(this);
    }

}
```

**In SandwichOrder class:**

```
namespace BotFormFlowTest
{
    public enum SandwichOptions
    {
        BLT, BlackForestHam, BuffaloChicken, ChickenAndBaconRanchMelt, ColdCutCombo, MeatballMarinara,
        OvenRoastedChicken, RoastBeef, RotisserieStyleChicken, SpicyItalian, SteakAndCheese, SweetOnionTeriyaki, Tuna,
        TurkeyBreast, Veggie
    };
    public enum LengthOptions { SixInch, FootLong };
    public enum BreadOptions { NineGrainWheat, NineGrainHoneyOat, Italian, ItalianHerbsAndCheese, Flatbread };
    public enum CheeseOptions { American, MontereyCheddar, Pepperjack };
    public enum ToppingOptions
    {
        Avocado, BananaPeppers, Cucumbers, GreenBellPeppers, Jalapenos,
        Lettuce, Olives, Pickles, RedOnion, Spinach, Tomatoes
    };
    public enum SauceOptions
    {
        ChipotleSouthwest, HoneyMustard, LightMayonnaise, RegularMayonnaise,
        Mustard, Oil, Pepper, Ranch, SweetOnion, Vinegar
    };


    [Serializable]
    public class SandwichOrder
    {
        public static string username = "User";

        public SandwichOrder(string uname)
        {
            username = uname;
        }

        public SandwichOptions? Sandwich;
        public LengthOptions? Length;
        public BreadOptions? Bread;
        public CheeseOptions? Cheese;
        public List<ToppingOptions> Toppings;
        public List<SauceOptions> Sauce;

        public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
                    .Message($"Hello {username}, Welcome to the simple sandwich order bot!")
                    .Build();
        }
    };
}
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Fei Han.